# de-coupling non-linear odes using change of variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-analysis

I have a pair of odes in $x$, $y$ and $t$ along with an extra variable $z$. It looks as follows:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{1}{z}f(x,y)$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{z}g(x,y)$

where $f$ and $g$ are real valued differentiable functions. Also,

$\frac{dz}{dt} = h(x,y)$

where $h$ is a real valued differentiable function.Can anyone suggest me a change of variable such that we get two self-contained odes (without any extra variable) and the system order is possibly reduced to two.

Answer (score 0):

Show using the chain rule that $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}.$$
Now, you have a general nonlinear ode.  This will give $y$ as a function of $x$.
Then,
$$z(t)\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y(x)) = h(x).$$  Separating variables,
$$\frac{dx}{h(x)} = \frac{dt}{z(t)}.$$
This will give $x$ as a function of $z$, and hence $t$.  $x(t) = x(z(t))$.

This answer assumes that $z$ is a known function of $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am also convinced that they are self-contained through a similar logic. But, I am trying to find the right change of variables to be able to express the odes independent of the third wheel. ;)

Comment: Just noticed that the system can also be expressed as **$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dz}(ln(z)f(x,y))$** and **$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d}{dz}(ln(z)g(x,y))$**. Not sure if this helps, but just another way of writing the same thing.